# How to extract matching strings into a defaultdict(set)? Python

Tags: python, string, translation, text-alignment, defaultdict

I have a textfile that has such lines (see below), where an english sentence is followed by a spanish sentence and the equivalent translation table delimited by "`{##}`". (if you know it it's the output for `giza-pp`)

> you have requested a debate on this subject in the course of the next
>   few days , during this part-session . {##} sus señorías han solicitado
>   un debate sobre el tema para los próximos días , en el curso de este
>   período de sesiones . {##} 0-0 0-1 1-2 2-3 3-4 4-5 5-6 6-7 7-8 8-9
>   12-10 13-11 14-11 15-12 16-13 17-14 9-15 10-16 11-17 18-18 17-19 19-21
>   20-22

The translation table is understood as such, `0-0 0-1` means that the 0th word in english (i.e. `you`) matches the 0th and 1st word in spanish (i.e. `sus señorías`)

Let's say i want to know what is the translation of `course` in spanish from the sentence, normally i'll do it this way:

```
from collections import defaultdict
eng, spa, trans =  x.split(" {##} ")
tt = defaultdict(set)
for s,t in [i.split("-") for i in trans.split(" ")]:
  tt[s].add(t)

query = 'course'
for i in spa.split(" ")[tt[eng.index(query)]]:
  print i
```

**is there a simple way to do the above? may `regex`? `line.find()`?**

After some tries i have to do this in order to cover many other issues like MWE and missing translations:

```
def getTranslation(gizaline,query):
    src, trg, trans =  gizaline.split(" {##} ")
    tt = defaultdict(set)
    for s,t in [i.split("-") for i in trans.split(" ")]:
        tt[int(s)].add(int(t))
    try:
        query_translated =[trg.split(" ")[i] for i in tt[src.split(" ").index(query)]]
    except ValueError:
        for i in src.split(" "):
            if "-"+query or query+"-" in i:
                query = i
                break
        query_translated =[trg.split(" ")[i] for i in tt[src.split(" ").index(query)]]

    if len(query_translated) > 0:
        return ":".join(query_translated)
    else:
        return "#NULL"
```

Comment: thanks for the note on the mistake. possibly someone might have a simpler way or at least faster way=)

Comment: Is there any particular reason you need `defaultdict(set)`?

Comment: actually a `defaultdict(list)` would do fine too, just want a set so that i dont get duplicates.

Comment: I'd use a `list` simply because it allows you to keep order, a `set` would not do that. As for duplicates, they can be beneficial - they show you the *order* that the words appear in spanish, even accounting for grammatical changes. If you don't allow duplicates, you'll only get one occurrence of each translation, and not ordered - meaning you don't know which translation is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That way works fine, but I'd do it slightly differently, using `list` instead of `set` so we can order the words correctly (`set` will output words in alphabetical order, not quite what we want):

**File: q_15125575.py**

```
#-*- encoding: utf8 -*-
from collections import defaultdict

INPUT = """you have requested a debate on this subject in the course of the next few days , during this part-session . {##} sus señorías han solicitado un debate sobre el tema para los próximos días , en el curso de este período de sesiones . {##} 0-0 0-1 1-2 2-3 3-4 4-5 5-6 6-7 7-8 8-9 12-10 13-11 14-11 15-12 16-13 17-14 9-15 10-16 11-17 18-18 17-19 19-21 20-22"""

if __name__ == "__main__":
    english, spanish, trans = INPUT.split(" {##} ")
    eng_words = english.split(' ')
    spa_words = spanish.split(' ')
    transtable = defaultdict(list)
    for e, s in [i.split('-') for i in trans.split(' ')]:
        transtable[eng_words[int(e)]].append(spa_words[int(s)])

    print(transtable['course'])
    print(transtable['you'])
    print(" ".join(transtable['course']))
    print(" ".join(transtable['you']))
```

**Output:**
['curso']
['sus', 'se\xc3\xb1or\xc3\xadas']
curso
sus señorías

It's slightly longer code as I'm using the actual words instead of the indexes - but this allows you to directly lookup from `transtable`

**However**, both your method and my method both fail on the same issue: Repeating words.
`print(" ".join(transtable['this'])`
gives:
`el este`
It's at least in the order that the words appear though, so it's workable. Want the first occurrence of `'this'` translated?
`transtable['this'][0]` would give you the first word.

And using your code:

```
tt = defaultdict(set)
for e, s in [i.split('-') for i in trans.split(' ')]:
    tt[int(e)].add(int(s))

query = 'this'
for i in tt[eng_words.index(query)]:
    print i
```

Gives:
`7`

Your code will only print the index of the *first* occurrence of a word.

Comment: Your code in the question as is won't even work though, it has quite a few errors. You're adding strings to tt{} (`tt[s].add(t)` would give `tt['0'] = '1'` for example). Then when you get the index, you're grabbing it from the raw string `eng`, not the split words. This index is a number, not string, so it will always return nothing. If you change it to be `tt[int(s)].add(int(t))`, the next problem is that it would fail because `spanish.split(" ")` is expecting an integer, not a set. And lastly, (assuming `eng` is the split words), `eng.index(query)` will still only return the first result.

Comment: thanks for noting the missing codes, i'll put my full code up. =)